# Get random character from random word and replace it

Tags: java, random

I managed to get a random word from my txt file. What it does is it reads 1000 random strings. What I need to do next is, when random string is read it replaces(or not) a random character of that string with * (* is used in another program as regex "."). Then this word needs to be saved to a new txt file.

First: I was thinking: read a random word, then calculate its length. Then do a random number and replace a character of that random number with *. Do you think that would be a good solution?

Second: Upper solution would always replace only 1 character right? But I want it to replace random number ( say 2 or 3 or 4) characters of a word.

```
public class random {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int dolzina=0;

        ArrayList random = new ArrayList();

        try {

            File file = new File("sortirane_besede.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            String vrstica;
            while ((vrstica = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                random.add(vrstica);
                //dolzina=random.size();
                //System.out.println(dolzina);

            }

            System.out.println("Generating 1000 random integers in range 0..129470.");

            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            for (int idx = 0; idx <= 1000; ++idx){
                int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(129470);
                System.out.println("Pozicija besede: " + randomInt);
                System.out.println(random.get(randomInt));
            }

            System.out.println("Done.");


        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**First:** I think you are right. If you have a word of length such as 6 you can generate random number with upper bound of 6 and then replace the character the random generator had resulted in lets say 4th. You can accomplish that by splitting the string into an array and then utilizing the index number of the array to be replaced.

You can use this as a point of start [with split function](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0438.html)

**Second:**
When you have your word split into array values then you can perform a random number generation on your array index within the bounds (2 to 4) you specify and then call the replace function from number 1.

**Lastly:** 
I think it would be worth to note that you can make somewhat non-biased decisions by utlising random number of 2 choices where 0 is true and 1 is false. 
Additionally, random generation in some cases can bring quite a bit of overhead to the performance of the application.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the performenca isnt an issue since i need txt which would then be used in main program so this program is irelevant

Answer (score -1):

import uuid

filename=[ ]

for i in range(0,999):

filename.append('word_%s.txt' % uuid.uuid4().____str___().replace('-',''))